# Infragistics ValueList Sort

Tags: sorting, infragistics

Scenatio is as follows:

I have a value-list which is of Type "Infragistics.Win.ValueList". and I want to sort the value-list. Let say I have the following values in Value-list.

"Value 1"
"Value 3".
"Value 2"
"Value 11"
"Value 22"

I'm using "value-list.SortStyle = ValueListSortStyle.Ascending;" to sort the value-list in ascending order. The output is as follows:

"Value 1"
"Value 11"
"Value 2"
"Value 22"
"Value 3".

This is becasue the sorting is based on string, where as the desired output is

"Value 1"
"Value 2"
"Value 3"
"Value 11"
"Value 22".

Also, ValueList doesn't expose the SortComparer property, so that I can write custom sort.

What should be my approach to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution though. It is definately not the best solution, but its giving me the desired output. Here it is.

After the values are stored in the value list I'm assinging the assinging all the values to a ArrayList(only the Text property). Then I'm sorting the ArrayList, which exposes the SortComparer property.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another property associated to each of your values? There are 'Value' and 'Text' properties on the value lists so if you could find something that sorts better to put in the 'Value' column I guess that might be ideal?

If not you could probably use an UltraDropDown / UltraCombo instead of a value list. They are like mini UltraGrids so you should be able to apply the custom sort to one of those the same as you would on a grid (not 100% sure  but I don't have Infragistics on this computer so I'll check at work tomorrow).

Comment: The "Value" and "text" properties have same data. For Ex: . Let say I have the following value in Value-list. "Value 1". The "Value" and "Text: properties both have "Value1". 

I cannot use UltraDropDown/ UltraCombo, because I'm fetching the values from the database, and saving them in a Value List. and then assinging this value list to the ValueList property of a UltraGrid.Column

Comment: You can use an UltraDropDown / UltraCombo in place of a ValueList in an UltraGrid's column. See this link: http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=1734